# DataTable to Excel Export Through Response Object

Tags: c#, asp.net, excel

I created an excel file using asp.net Response object. But in this file, long numbers automatically change to scientific notation. How can I prevent this?

```
private void WriteToExcelFile(DataTable dt)
{
StringWriter sw = new StringWriter();


sw.Write("Kolon_1\t");
sw.Write("Kolon_2\t");


for (int i = 0; i < dt.Rows.Count; i++)
{
DataRow dr = dt.Rows[i];

sw.Write("\n");
sw.Write(dr["Ad"].ToString() + "\t");
sw.Write(dr["Numara"].ToString() + "\t");


}


Response.Output.Write(sw.ToString());
}
```

Answer (score 4):

I reccomend that you use [EPPlus](http://epplus.codeplex.com/) and export DataTable into real xlsx file, it's pretty simple, with this method you can create excel file and store it to memory stream:

```
public static MemoryStream DataTableToExcelXlsx(DataTable table, string sheetName)
{
  MemoryStream Result = new MemoryStream();
  ExcelPackage pack = new ExcelPackage();
  ExcelWorksheet ws = pack.Workbook.Worksheets.Add(sheetName);

  int col = 1;
  int row = 1;
  foreach (DataRow rw in table.Rows)
  {
    foreach (DataColumn cl in table.Columns)
    {
      if (rw[cl.ColumnName] != DBNull.Value)
        ws.Cells[row, col].Value = rw[cl.ColumnName].ToString();
      col++;
    }
    row++;
    col = 1;
  }

  pack.SaveAs(Result);
  return Result;
}
```

and then serve that stream to client :

```
MemoryStream ms = DataTableToExcelXlsx(myDataTable, "Sheet1");
ms.WriteTo(Response.OutputStream);
Response.ContentType = "application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet";
Response.AddHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment;filename=DataTable.xlsx");
Response.StatusCode = 200;
```

Comment: Thank you so much for your answer but I am not allowed to use any office library. But I will remember your answer if I need to use.

Answer (score 0):

we apply style

```
r.Cells[columnIndex].Attributes.Add("class", "text"); 
    System.Text.StringBuilder style = new System.Text.StringBuilder();
                style.Append("<style>");
                style.Append("." + "text" + " { mso-number-format:" + "\\@;" + " }");
                style.Append("</style>");
                response.Clear();
                Response.Buffer = true;
                //response.Charset = "";
                //response.Write(sw.ToString());
                Response.Write(style.ToString());
```

Sample function

```
  public void GenerateXLS(string pFileName, DataTable pdtSource)
        {
            HttpResponse response = HttpContext.Current.Response;
            response.Clear();
            response.Charset = "";
            // set the response mime type for excel 

            if ((pFileName + "-").ToLower().Contains(".xlsx-"))
            {
                response.ContentType = "application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet";
            }
            else
            {
                response.ContentType = "application/vnd.ms-excel";
            }

            response.AddHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment;filename=\"" + pFileName + "\"");

            // create a string writer 
            using (StringWriter sw = new StringWriter())
            {
                using (HtmlTextWriter htw = new HtmlTextWriter(sw))
                {
                    // instantiate a datagrid 
                    GridView gvExport = new GridView();
                    gvExport.DataSource = pdtSource;
                    gvExport.DataBind();
                    //(start): require for date format issue
                    HtmlTextWriter hw = new HtmlTextWriter(sw);

                    foreach (GridViewRow r in gvExport.Rows)
                    {
                        if (r.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow)
                        {
                            for (int columnIndex = 0; columnIndex < r.Cells.Count; columnIndex++)
                            {
                                r.Cells[columnIndex].Attributes.Add("class", "text");
                            }
                        }
                    }
                    //(end): require for date format issue

                    gvExport.RenderControl(htw);
                    //(start): require for date format issue
                    System.Text.StringBuilder style = new System.Text.StringBuilder();
                    style.Append("<style>");
                    style.Append("." + "text" + " { mso-number-format:" + "\\@;" + " }");
                    style.Append("</style>");
                    response.Clear();
                    Response.Buffer = true;
                    //response.Charset = "";
                    //response.Write(sw.ToString());
                    Response.Write(style.ToString());
                    Response.Output.Write(sw.ToString());
                    Response.Flush();
                    //(end): require for date format issue
                    try
                    {
                        response.End();
                    }
                    catch (Exception err)
                    {

                    }
                    //HttpContext.Current.ApplicationInstance.CompleteRequest();
                }
            }
        }
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I have already tried this but it did not work. I will try again with this sample function.

Answer (score 0):

> DataTable to Excel Export Through Response Object

A simple way to do this is to add my free C# class to your project, then add one line of code, to call it's "CreateExcelDocument" function:

```
DataTable dt = CreateSampleData();
string excelFilename = "C:\\Sample.xlsx";
CreateExcelFile.CreateExcelDocument(ds, excelFilename);
```

And that's it !

Full details (with free downloadable source code, and an example project) here:

[Export to Excel C# class](http://mikesknowledgebase.com/pages/CSharp/ExportToExcel.htm)

My library uses the free *Microsoft OpenXML* libraries (also provided in my downloads) to write the file, so you don't have to use the heavyweight VSTO libraries, or have Excel installed on your server.

Also, it creates a real .xlsx file, rather than some other methods which write a stream of data to a comma-separated text file, but name it as a .xls file.